# iTunes 11 interface illegible

Tags: iphone, itunes

I'm having issues with the iTunes interface being illegible. It is especially a problem in the iPhone management area. I have searched the world for similar issues and so far nothing has turned up. Hoping someone here has ideas on how to resolve. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This persists after quitting and reopening iTunes?

Comment: Indeed it does. I've had this issue for ~1 month. I've run Cocktail (clear caches, repair permission, run scripts) and rebooted multiple times since this issue began for me.

Comment: Move iTunes.app to the trash and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this trashing my preferences `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.itunes`. I don't know why I didn't do this earlier as it really should have been one of the first things to try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you MD5'd iTunes.app? The easiest solution might be to backup your library and completely reinstall iTunes, being sure to clear out anything in ~/Library, /Library and the like.

Comment: I downloaded and reinstalled. I also deleted the ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunes. The issue persists.